# Front end и Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring

До этого момента, я весь фронт делал с помощью стандартных JSP, HTML, CSS. Но теперь решил посмотреть в сторону JavaScript-фреймворков.

И вот тут у меня ступор. Я не понимаю в какую сторону смотреть, с чего начать? Не в плане изучения JavaScript, а как скрестить весь этот back на Spring, который возвращает JSON объекты, и фронт, который, как пример, принимает эти JSON и сделает что-нибудь банальное с ними. Есть варианты полностью избавиться от стандартных view (JSP, Thymeleaf) и использовать полностью независимые JavaScript-фреймворки (Vue, React)? А не смесь JSP, в котором вызывается функция JavaScript, которая лежит в какой-нибудь папке, на мой взгляд, это какой-то неправильный подход. Если ошибаюсь — поправьте.

Comment: Найдите простенький пример и на нем потренируйтесь. Здесь неплохо разъясняется на примере Spring and Angular - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Есть варианты полносью избавиться от стандартных view(jsp,thymeleaf)и использовать полностью независимые js фреймворки(vue,react)?

Всё, конечно же, реально. Разрабатываем `api` в виде обычного `spring boot` приложения, без какого-либо фронта (без `jsp` и подобного, просто эндпоинты, отдающие `json`). После, разрабатываем фронтовое приложение на любом javascript фрейморке, который вам нравится. Фронтовое приложение будет обращаться к `api` за информацией и рендерить статику.

Теперь у нас есть отдельно фронт и отдельно бек, и, есть два подхода, как заставить их работать вместе.

**Первый подход: единый сервер**

- создаём внутри `spring boot` проекта какой-то каталог, к примеру `react`,
- копируем туда весь свой фронт-проект вместе с `npm` и `webpack` конфигами (либо любыми другими сборщиками, которые вы используете)
- на этапе компиляции и сборки spring-boot приложения, добавляем отдельную стадию, которая собирает зависимости и компилирует ваш фронт-энд (существуют готовые maven-плагины)
- получившиеся статические файлы (`.js`, `.css` и т.п.) во время сборки копируем в папку `resources` `spring` приложения
- настраиваем `spring` на раздачу получившейся статики, по запросам, которые не начинаются с `/api`

У этого подхода есть существенный минус: настройка всего процесса сборки и запуска довольно муторная и таит много подводных камней.

**Второй подход: отдельные сервера**

- поднимаем отдельно `spring boot` сервер, обслуживающий только api запросы
- поднимаем отдельно разработанное `react/angular/vue` приложение раздающее статику и делающее запросы к апи (на отдельном порту одной физической машины, или на отдельной машине). Используем родной для javascript-а `node` сервер.

Этот подход требует поддержки двух отдельных серверов, а также грамотной настройки канала общения между ними.

P.S.если всё вышеперечисленное выглядит сложным, есть замечательный проект [Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/), который умеет генерировать готовые Spring Boot + React/Angular/Vue/многочегоещё приложения. Можно сгененировать парочку приложений и черпать вдохновение оттуда.

Comment: очень часто видел именно первый подход.Спасибо)